# What is the average recovery time for cold and catarrh

Tags: infection, water, immune-system, common-cold, catarrh

I've been having cold and catarrh for the past one week. I don't want to disturb my parents about medicines, so I drink lots of water everyday, but doesn't seem to have any improvement.

**Q1: What is the average recovery time for the body to fight off the infection.**